# record using /pulse/simple.h

Tags: c, ubuntu, audio-recording, pulseaudio

i am trying to record my voice from the microphone on my laptop using the simple.h `pulseaudio` header file into an array, but i cant seem to figure it out. Every time i record and i replay my recording , it is a high pitched beep i followed examples, etc but i can't seem to get this down can someone please help me . 
I am basically hacking the example "parec-simple.c" given in the doxygen page. I've tried routing the output of `buf` to `stdout`, then using libre-office calc to plot a graph to see if the output looks anything like sound but it does not.

here is the code i used

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <pulse/simple.h>
#include <pulse/error.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

FILE *output; 

/* A simple routine calling UNIX write() in a loop */
void loop_write(uint8_t *data) {
  register int size = 1023;

while (size > 0) 
{
    fprintf(output,"%"SCNu8"\n",data[size]  )  ;    
        size --;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
output = fopen("/home/donnell/output", "w");

/* The sample type to use */
static const pa_sample_spec ss = {
    .format = PA_SAMPLE_S16LE,
    .rate = 41000,
    .channels = 2
};
pa_simple *s = NULL;
int ret = 1;
int error;

/* Create the recording stream */
if (!(s = pa_simple_new(NULL, argv[0], PA_STREAM_RECORD, NULL,  "record", &ss, NULL, NULL, &error))) {
    fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_new() failed: %s\n",   pa_strerror(error));
    goto finish;
}

for (;;) {
    uint8_t buf[BUFSIZE];

    /* Record some data ... */
    if (pa_simple_read(s, buf, sizeof(buf), &error) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_read() failed: %s\n",  pa_strerror(error));
        goto finish;
    }

   /* and write it to fle*/
loop_write(buf);

}

ret = 0;

finish:

if (s)
    pa_simple_free(s);

return ret;
}
```

Comment: Basic troubleshooting I would recommend: Look for a sound recorder app on your Ubuntu desktop (I know there is at least one installed by default) and try recording audio. You may need to open the audio mixer to enable the microphone or turn up the recording volume. Establish that baseline of functionality before going any farther with this exercise.